# Cassandra: what protocol used in SSTableLoader?

Tags: load, cassandra, bulk

Imho, there are 2 available protocols to connect client app to cassandra server: CQL and thrift.

What protocol used by SSTableLoader utility to load sstables to cassandra cluster? 
As I understand it does not use CQL because it is impossible to do bulk loading with good performance via CQL.

If thrift then the question is: how it uses thrift for bulk loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, **[thrift is used](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/BulkLoader.java#L234)**.

> it is impossible to do bulk loading with good performance via CQL

Not really true, its just that the functionality has already been implemented and there's no reason for re-implementing it in CQL because thrift wont be getting dropped (allows for good backwards compatibility)

To sum it up, the sstables are read in, a thrift client is created for streaming said data and then a *LoaderFuture* task is created to coordinate the streaming.

Comment: Thnx! How I can use it in c++ client? I.e. c++ app does bulk loading the sstables to cassandra cluster. How do you think is it possible? What I need to use? thrift, OpenSSL.. what else?

Comment: This is no longer true: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/f698cc228452e847e3ad46bd8178549cf8171767